# unable to find the scope of dynamically created fields in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create the form in which user can dynamically add the input field by pressing the button. but I am not able to fetch the value of that input field to controller?
The following is my form:

```
<div ng-repeat="skill in skill_set">
    <label>Skill-name</label>
    <input type="text"name="" ng-model="skill.sName" placeholder="enter your skills here">
    <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeSkill()">-</button>
</div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addNewSkill()">Add more Skills</button>
    <a ui-sref="/"  ng-click="createMeetup()"> Next Section </a>
```

my controller is defined as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('meetupApp', ['ngResource','ui.router']);
app.controller('mainCrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$location', function ($scope, $resource, $location) {
  $scope.skill_set = [{id: 'skill1'}];

  $scope.addNewSkill = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.skill_set.length+1;
    $scope.skill_set.push({'id':'skill'+newItemNo});
    };

  $scope.removeSkill = function() {
    var lastItem = $scope.skill_set.length-1;
    $scope.skill_set.splice(lastItem);
    };

  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var employee = new Employee();
    console.log("the skill set is"+ $scope.skill_set.sName);
    employee.skills =[{skill_name: $scope.skill_set.sName}] ;
    employee.$save();
    };
}]);
```

Employee is the mongodb document where skills is array of skill_name.
When I am consoling the skill set. it showing me "the skill set is undefined"
how do I get the value from input field to controller?
Small piece of help is really appreciated!!!!

Comment: Please format your code a little and remove the unnecessary clutter?

Comment: @MikkoViitala I have formatted the code and removed unneccessary things. can you help me with my functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You are filling sName during iteration. So if you wan't to reach a skill name, the code would look like `$scope.skill_set[iteration].sName`

If you wan't an array of skill name, make a loop over skill_set to create the proper array.

---

But it would be easier to manipulate your $scope with `ng-model="skill.skill_name"`

And assign `employee.skills = $scope.skill_set;`

You did add an id to the model, to keep it clean, you must avoid using Id property, so add new items with: `$scope.skill_set.push({'skill_name':''+});`

`$scope.skill_set` should look like

```
[
      {'skill_name' : "skillname1"},
      {'skill_name' : "skillname2"},
      {'skill_name' : "skillname3"}
]
```

Or if you want an array with only skill names

```
var skillNames = [];
for (skill in $scope.skill_set)
{
    skillNames.push(skill.skill_Name);
}
 employee.skills = {'skill_name' : skillNames};
```

And `employee.skills` would look like

`{ 'skill_name' : [ "skillname1", "skillname2", "skillname3" ]}`

---

V2 : code clean

But it would be easier to manipulate your $scope with `ng-model="skill"`

And assign `employee.skills = {'skill_name' : $scope.skill_set};`

You did add an id to the model, to keep it clean, you must avoid using Id property, so add new items with: `$scope.skill_set.push({''});`

And `employee.skills` would look like

`{ 'skill_name' : [ "skillname1", "skillname2", "skillname3" ]}`

---

I keep first solution, because i'm not sure of what kind of data format you need.

Comment: I tried do that but it consoles "the skill set is[object Object]"

Comment: What property did you try to display, $scope.skill_set ? if yes, it is the expected result.

Comment: yes, I tried to display $scope.skill_set. what I want to do is to add all the skill_name to employee.skills = [{skill_name: $scope.skill_set}] in an array format so that I can send employee.skills.skill_name into database